# Project/Ticket Managment

Tags: software-development, software, task-management

I have recently been tasked with finding and implementing a solution for task/project management.

I have come here for some suggestions to see what you use. There are however some rather specific requirements:

**Absolute MUSTS**

- Must be open source
- Must be web based
- Contain Customer Database
- Simple interface/ Easy to use

**Advantages**

- Runs on SQL Server 2005+
- Written on the .NET Platform

The software will be being used within a small software company to assign tasks to employees and to track the progress of tasks. Some sort of timesheet would be advantageous (to see what time has been spent on what task)

I look forward to your responses!

Comment: Welcome to PMSE! Questions asking us to recommend or find tools, books, study materials, or other off-site resources are off-topic as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, please ask targeted questions about a specific project management knowledge domain.

Comment: Related answer: http://pm.stackexchange.com/a/9754/4271.

Comment: This is targeted. I am not looking for opinionated answers, I am looking for solutions other people may have come across that meet exact criteria. I have read the rules on posting and believe there can be correct answers here, so it adheres to the rules.

Comment: "This site is NOT about tool recommendations." See http://pm.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. Good luck!

Comment: Not a tool recommendation. A recommendation would imply I am asking people about personal preference. There is a clear set of specifications for the answer.

See "Tool Usage in Project Management" http://pm.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Your question is within the category of questions that PM:SE has consistently refused to discuss.  I believe the help file you reference is intended to convey that we'll discuss how to use tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is anything think out there that will check all your boxes.  The only thing that I have used that even comes close is "The Trac Project".  Unfortunately, it is written in Python and runs on Linux, does not support SQL Server.  The other product that comes to mind is TFS Team Foundation Services but here again it is missing many of the buckets you are trying to fill.  Just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

You ask for what is not possible.  Having a great open sourced project to make your own generally means it isn't going to be extremely easy to use like some of the better solutions available on the web.  Have you looked into Trello?

https://trello.com/

I have just recently started using it but am amazed at what it offers.  Very nice and easy to use interfaces, very clean and flexible, and also can be customized to your needs.  Downside is it is not open-source and does not rely on .NET framework (appears to work on top of Mongo)